# Need to await a function that is inside of a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-redux, auth0

I am using Auth0 to perform authentication in my React app.

Upon the default reroute that Auth0 performs after getting the information, I need to parse the hash that it returns then use some of the returned into to save the auth Token to the store for other tasks later. However this function that handles storing of the authToken occurs in the callback of parseHash (an auth0 function).

How can I wait for handleLogin() (the function being called in the callback) to complete before moving on with other tasks? I cannot make parseHash() async as I don't have real access to it.

Root.tsx

```
`if (this.props.location.hash) {
      this.props.authClient.parseHash(
        { hash: this.props.location.hash },
        (err, authResult) => handleLogin(err, authResult, this.props.dispatch)
      );
    }
  }`
```

handleLogin.ts

```
`export const handleLogin = (
  err: Auth0ParseHashError | null,
  authResult: Auth0DecodedHash | null,
  dispatch: Dispatch
) => {
  if (authResult) {
    const userId = authResult.idTokenPayload.sub;
    dispatch(
      setAuthToken({
        token: {
          accessToken: authResult.idToken,
          userId
        }
      })
    );
  }
};`
```

This is information that is supplied about parseHash() from Auth0

```
`parseHash(
    options: ParseHashOptions,
    callback: Auth0Callback<Auth0DecodedHash | null, Auth0ParseHashError>
  ): void;`

  `Decodes the id_token and verifies  the nonce.
  @param callback: function(err, {payload, transaction})`
```

Comment: When you dispatch `setAuthToken`, where is it stored?

Comment: How can this line `(err, authResult) => handleLogin(err, authResult, this.props.dispatch)` be a parameter of  your `parseHash()` function if `handleLogin()` does not return anything ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [redux thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) then the dispatch will be returning a promise. You should be able to use `.then` for example

```
handleLogin(err, authResult, this.props.dispatch).then(() => {/*other task code here*/})
```

You'll also need to return the dispatch from your `handleLogin` function

Comment: sorry, @Ghojzilla, I not sure I understand. handleLogin() itself is the callback code. Ideally I would want to make the function where it is called, parseHash() async and then await handleLogin(), however I do not have full access to the parseHash() function as it is a built-in Auth0 method.

Comment: When you say, 'before moving on with other tasks" are you able to put these other tasks inside the .then function? Even if you put the other tasks in a function that you call from inside the then? Will edit the answer if this is a possibility for you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const test = async () => {
  await example();
  console.log(`finished !`);
}

function example() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
}

test();
```

Then for your case I would say :
**Inside an async function**

```js
// Async anonymous function that directly executes
(async() => {
    const ret = await (err, authResult) => handleLogin(err, authResult, this.props.dispatch);

    if (this.props.location.hash) {
        this.props.authClient.parseHash(
            { hash: this.props.location.hash },
            ret
        );
    }
})()
```

The thing is, `handleLogin()` does not seem to return anything, so `ret` might stay null. Maybe there is a problem with your logic.

Remember that:

```js
(x) => x
```

is the same as:

```js
(x) => { return x; }
```

, with arrow functions.

Comment: I've tried a few variations of this, but then I am presented with the error: "'await' expression is only allowed within an async function." Adding async to the containing function does not work either.

Comment: I edited my answer, now it should work try it and tell me @sthomas